# make folder with name "..." in c or c#

Tags: c#, c, windows

"WinMend" is a software for hiding folders in windows by creating a folder with name "..." and another folder with name "cn" in that.

I can do this in Linux and this works good because you cannot open cn folder cause an error in windows 7 !

but in windows I cannot create a folder with this name, "...", not in c not in c#, so please help me.

Comment: Hmmm... `WinMend` must be hacking the folder names somehow behind the scenes, maybe by modifying the file itself or the file system. Apparently it is possible to do this using a program such as HxD: http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ ... This would be a clue how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Is the folder name 3 periods or a [horizontal ellipsis character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm)?

Answer (score 4):

In windows a folder name cannot end with a period.

Edit: It was correctly pointed out I could have explained better, so apologies about that.

See here for information regarding naming file and folder naming conventions for windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see this folder and I can open this.but the cn folder is not accessable.and this software do this.

Comment: While this is a correct answer, and got my up vote, I feel as though you could have lined something that backed up you answer. Something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx for example

Comment: I have read all of this and then I have asked the question.

Comment: this software do this , creating folder named "...".

Comment: do you want the pic of folder and name and error to believe me?

Comment: one more thing, so how the hiding software hide folder in external hdd?

Comment: While it may be supported by the underlying file system, it is not supported by Windows.

Comment: you are like stone! I said this software doing this in windows, and I have understand this by debugging software in linux.